# How to remove this dart "detail" message in VSCode

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code

When I type the parentheses of a Widget, this "message" shows. What annoying me most is that I have to close it by clicking somewhere with the mouse.

Is that any ways to disable is function?
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to disable dart & flutter VScode extensions ?

Comment: @ethicnology If I disable these two extensions, it won't show the dart suggestion either. I just want to disable that sxxt.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this is related to the spicify language.

Try to disable the hover action in VSCode settings.json file:

```
"editor.hover.enabled": false
```

Or you can make it disappear when the mouse hover on it.

```
"editor.hover.sticky": false
```

Comment: Seems that it doesn't work... :(